# Getting Error while enabling Stats for wso2 esb API and EndPoint

Tags: ssl, wso2-api-manager, wso2, ibm-api-management

I have enabled Stats for my API and Endpoints from Enterprise Integrator Dashboard. I have also made true following properties in /conf/synapse.properties as given below.

```
mediation.flow.statistics.enable=true
mediation.flow.statistics.tracer.collect.payloads=true
mediation.flow.statistics.tracer.collect.properties=true
mediation.flow.statistics.collect.all=true
```

Then I have started Enterprise Integrator Analytics Dashboard 6.6.0 and Started Server from Integration studio which deploys my two applications. It gives me an Integrator Dashboard URL as given **https://192.168.0.75:9443/carbon/**

I have moved to the EndPoints section and API section and Enable Tracing and Enable Statistics from there.
Then have Open Analytics dashboard using URL as given below.
**https://192.168.0.75:9643/portal**

But I did not find any data then. then I again request from the postman and I find some errors in my as a console as given below.

```
[2020-03-05 13:52:27,005]  WARN {org.wso2.carbon.databridge.agent.endpoint.DataEndpointGroup} - No receiver is reachable at reconnection, will try to reconnect every 30 sec
[2020-03-05 13:52:29,015] ERROR {org.wso2.carbon.databridge.agent.endpoint.DataEndpointConnectionWorker} - Error while trying to connect to the endpoint. Cannot borrow client for ssl://localhost:7712 org.wso2.carbon.databridge.agent.exception.DataEndpointAuthenticationException: Cannot borrow client for ssl://localhost:7712
    at org.wso2.carbon.databridge.agent.endpoint.DataEndpointConnectionWorker.connect(DataEndpointConnectionWorker.java:147)
    at org.wso2.carbon.databridge.agent.endpoint.DataEndpointConnectionWorker.run(DataEndpointConnectionWorker.java:59)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: org.wso2.carbon.databridge.agent.exception.DataEndpointSecurityException: Error while trying to connect to ssl://localhost:7712
    at org.wso2.carbon.databridge.agent.endpoint.thrift.ThriftSecureClientPoolFactory.createClient(ThriftSecureClientPoolFactory.java:81)
    at org.wso2.carbon.databridge.agent.client.AbstractClientPoolFactory.makeObject(AbstractClientPoolFactory.java:39)
    at org.apache.commons.pool.impl.GenericKeyedObjectPool.borrowObject(GenericKeyedObjectPool.java:1212)
    at org.wso2.carbon.databridge.agent.endpoint.DataEndpointConnectionWorker.connect(DataEndpointConnectionWorker.java:137)
    ... 6 more
Caused by: org.apache.thrift.transport.TTransportException: Could not connect to localhost on port 7712
    at org.apache.thrift.transport.TSSLTransportFactory.createClient(TSSLTransportFactory.java:237)
    at org.apache.thrift.transport.TSSLTransportFactory.getClientSocket(TSSLTransportFactory.java:169)
    at org.wso2.carbon.databridge.agent.endpoint.thrift.ThriftSecureClientPoolFactory.createClient(ThriftSecureClientPoolFactory.java:64)
    ... 9 more
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect
    at java.net.TwoStacksPlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:350)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:206)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:188)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:172)
    at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:589)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.connect(SSLSocketImpl.java:666)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.<init>(SSLSocketImpl.java:426)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketFactoryImpl.createSocket(SSLSocketFactoryImpl.java:88)
    at org.apache.thrift.transport.TSSLTransportFactory.createClient(TSSLTransportFactory.java:233)
    ... 11 more
```

**Please Guide me on what I am doing wrong?**

Details :- 
Integration Studio:-  Version 7.0.0
Enterprise Integrator:- Version 6.6.0
Server Created using the above integrator only.

Answer (score 1):

Below is the point which I follow and It's working for me.
1. Check TCP and SSL Port in Carbon.XML in your ESB Integrator Directory config.

2. Check the same ports in  Integrator Directory_Version(6.6.0) \repository\deployment\server\eventpublishers. There you find two files named MessageFlowConfigurationPublisher and MessageFlowStatisticsPublisher Check the same TCP AND SSL port the same as above given under Analytics in Carbon.xml.
3. Make Given property as true ..Mention in Question above.
4. **Then first Start your Analytics Worker**
5. **Start your Analytics Dashboard**
6. At last start, Your ESB server, which runs your wso2 ESB application. It will give your carbon home URL (integrator dashboard URL). In that enable stats and tracking for all API's and endpoints and at last hit one of your API.
7. Take the Analytics Dashboard URL from Point 5 work and login with admin/admin.
8. You can able to see stats and tracing there.

[image: API Stats and Tracing]